# How to attach a click handler with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

This is the html part of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h>
            <title> This page</title>
        </h>
    </head>
     <body>
         <button id = "go-button" >GO</button>
         <script src="main.js"></script> 
     </body>
</html>
```

This is the javaScript part of my code:

```js
function buttonClicked(){
    console.log("button clicked");
}

var btn = document.getElementById("go-button");

btn.addEventListener("clicked", buttonClicked);
```

Whenever i try to print it on console, it does not show any output, i am confused

Comment: change "clicked" to "click"

Comment: What are the `<h>` tags in your HTML? These are not valid elements

Comment: You should also get rid of spaces between your id and `go-button`. `id = "go-button"` should be `id="go-button"`

Comment: Actually , i am in learning stage , and i added a small snippet of my HTML part. And yes spelling was wrong it worked thanks. And yeah i will remove the spacing and useless parts. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no event clicked but click:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct `clicked` to `click` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The addEventListener function takes two parameters one is the event and  second the function to be executed, you have speelled the first parameter wrong.

```
btn.addEventListener ('click', buttonClicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

The event name is "click", not "clicked"